# Create correlated pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

If you have a two column dataframe containing daily temperatures from two countries over the course of a year, it is easy to calculate the correlation of those columns using pandas corr, eg:

```
Country A   Country B
10          20
11          20
10          22
9           23

df.corr()
```

Is there a way to somehow generate a pandas series based on an initial column that will have a specified correlation? In other words, if I only have one list of temperatures from one country, I want to generate a second list that has a 0.8 correlation to the first list, eg:

```
Country A   Country B
10          
11          
10          
9
```

Create a second list of temperatures based on Country A that will have a 0.8 correlation. Maybe there is some way using numpy or a python statistical package to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is certainly possible. The corr method uses Pearsons r by default. You can plug into the equation one column, and find some values for the other column that result into the desired correlation. The problem is, there are many solutions and you may not like the one you get.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from scipy.optimize import minimize

data = pd.DataFrame({'Country A': [10, 11, 10, 9]})

data['Country B'] = minimize(lambda x: abs(0.8 - pearsonr(data['Country A'], x)[0]), 
                             np.random.rand(len(data['Country A']))).x
```

I use the *scipy.optimize.minimize* function to minimize the absolute value of (0.8 - correlation). To achieve the minimum of 0, the correlation must equal 0.8.

You described that you want to generate values which resemble temperatures. The objective function, which you supply can also be more sophisticated. Say, you want to generate temperatures, which do not have a standard deviation greater than 5 and which may only lie between 5 and 25. The latter you can supply as bounds to the minimize function. The former you have to consider in the objective function.

```
from random import randint

def fun(x):
    if np.std(x) >= 5:
        return np.std(x)
    return abs(0.8 - pearsonr(data['Country A'], x)[0])

data['Country B'] = minimize(fun, [randint(5, 25) for _ in range(365)], 
                             method = 'SLSQP', bounds = [(5, 25) for _ in range(365)]).x
```

This approach makes sure that the values for the generated series follow a certain distribution.